# Hawtio server-side saved connections

Tags: hawtio

I have setup connections to some activemq servers. Is it possible to setup the connections is such a way that these connections will be accessible for other users of hawtio, in their own browsers (not just on mine...)?

Answer (score 1):

No not currently, those connections is saved in your local browser settings.

If they were able to be shared, how would you envision that should happen, as there need to be some shared store somewhere where the information can be stored, and then each brower must then be setup to use that shared storage etc.

Comment: Could the settings be persisted within the hawtio config directory?

Comment: With service discovery tools like consul etal in the picture, it is imperative for the need to have some sort of central management console. A .conf file local would be great start. We can rely of tools like consul-template to rewrite the .conf file on changes or discovery.

Comment: There is a new issue open on Hawtio: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2268